# Curvature calculation of the ellipse at the end of its axes

Tags: conic-sections, curvature

Calculate the curvature of the ellipse (of which the minor axis is *b* and the major axis is *a*) at the end of each axes!

Comment: Which ellipse? Please also add your own work so we can better help you.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1159928/radius-vs-radius-of-curvature-of-an-ellipse

Comment: It's not specific, the equation needs to be written with parameters. This is the only sectence by which the exercise needs to be done. I'm just curious about the result, but thank you @bhattacharjee

Answer (score 2):

Here's a geometric construction for the radius of curvature at point $P$ of an ellipse with foci $A$ and $B$.

- Construct the bisector $n$ of $\angle APB$, which is the normal at $P$.
- Construct on ray $n$ points $H$ and $K$, such that $PH$ and $PK$ are the diameters of the circles tangent to the ellipse at $P$ and passing through $A$ and $B$ respectively (note that $\angle PAH=\angle PBK=90°$).
- The radius of curvature is the harmonic mean of $PH$ and $PK$.

PROOF.

Let $P'$ be a point on the ellipse near to $P$ and let normal lines at $P$ and $P'$ meet at $C$. If we set
$$
\alpha=\angle PAP',\quad \beta=\angle PBP',\quad \theta=\angle PCP',
$$
then by angle chasing it is easy to find that
$$
2\theta=\alpha+\beta.
$$
Consider now the circle through $APP'$, let $d_A$ be its diameter and $a$ its arc $PP'$ subtended by $\alpha$: we have then $a=\alpha d_A$. We can repeat the same reasoning for the circles through $BPP'$ and $CPP'$, with diameters $d_B$ and $d_C$, and arcs: $b=\beta d_B$, $c=\theta d_C$. Obtaining $\alpha$, $\beta$ and $\theta$ from these equalities, and plugging them into the above equation gives then:
$$
2{c\over d_C}={a\over d_A}+{b\over d_B},
$$
which can be rearranged as:
$$
{1\over d_C}={1\over2}\left({a/c\over d_A}+{b/c\over d_B}\right).
$$
In the limit $P'\to P$, the circles through $APP'$ and $BPP'$ tend to the circles tangent to the ellipse at $P$ and passing through $A$ and $B$ respectively, while $C$ tends to the center of the osculating circle at $P$. Hence $d_C$ tends to the radius of curvature $\rho$ at $P$, while $d_A$ and $d_B$ tend to $PH$ and $PK$ defined above. In addition, both $a/c$ and $b/c$ tend to $1$ as $P'\to P$. The above equation implies then:
$$
{1\over \rho}={1\over2}\left({1\over PH}+{1\over PK}\right),
$$
as it was to be proved.

[image]

The same argument can be repeated for a hyperbola and a parabola, leading to
$$
{1\over \rho}={1\over2}\left|{1\over PH}-{1\over PK}\right|
\quad\text{and}\quad
\rho=2PH
$$
respectively. A detailed explanation for the parabola can be found [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4483650/255730).