# Fixing an orbit in space using r and v (Keplerian orbits)

Tags: geometry, physics, conic-sections, mathematical-astronomy

I'm wondering what would be a good geometric method to compute orbital elements that fix the orbit in space, given that one is given the position vector $\vec{r}$ and the velocity vector $\vec{v}$ for a Keplerian orbit.

I know that from vis-visa equation, one gets the semi-major axis *a* and uses the $\vec{v} \times \vec{h} $, where $\vec{h}$ is the specific angular momentum ($\vec{r}\times\vec{v} $) of the orbiting body, to compute the eccentricity vector $\vec{e}$ using the following equation, where $\mu$ is the standard gravitational parameter.

$$
\vec{e}=\frac{\vec{v} \times \vec{h}}{\mu} - \frac{\vec{r}}{r}
$$

What other elements we need to compute in order to fix the orbit or is it enough ? I'd like to hear if anyone has some ideas with possibly a geometric visualization.

Thank you in advance !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me show, first of all, a construction for the radius of curvature of a conic ([see here for a proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3455731/curvature-calculation-of-the-ellipse-at-the-end-of-its-axes/3457101#3457101)).

Let $P$ be a point on a conic with foci $S$ and $S'$. The bisectors of the angles formed by lines $PS$ and $PS'$ are the tangent and normal at $P$ (for a parabola these are the bisectors of the angles formed by $PS$ with the parallel to the axis passing through $P$). From $S$ and $S'$ construct the perpendiculars to $PS$ and $PS'$ respectively, intersecting the normal at $N$ and $N'$ (see figure below). The radius of curvature $\rho=PC$ can be then computed from:
$$
\tag{1}
{1\over \rho}={1\over2}\left({1\over PN}\pm{1\over PN'}\right),
$$
where one has to take sign $+$ for an ellipse and $-$ for a hyperbola (in the case of a hyperbola $S$ must be the focus of the branch where $P$ lies).
The special case of a parabola can be obtained by letting $S'\to\infty$, that is:
$\rho = 2PN$.

[image]

Suppose now we have a point mass $P$ subject to gravitational attraction from a fixed point $S$. We know at a certain instant of time the position of $P$, its velocity $v$ (magnitude and direction) and from Newton's law of gravitation we also know its acceleration $a$ (directed towards $S$).

The line through $P$ perpendicular to the velocity is the normal to the orbit at $P$. We can construct the line through $S$ perpendicular to $PS$, intersecting the normal at $N$. And we can construct the normal acceleration $a_n$ by projecting $a$ onto the normal (see figure below).

$a_n$ is connected to the radius of curvature $\rho$ at $P$ by the well-known kinematical relation
$$
a_n={v^2\over \rho},
$$
hence we can compute $\rho$ as
$$
\rho={v^2\over a_n}.
$$
We can then use $(1)$ to find $PN'$:
$$
{1\over PN'}=\pm\left({2\over \rho}-{1\over PN}\right),
$$
where the sign of $2/\rho-1/PN$ (which is the same as the sign of $2PN-\rho$)  determines the shape of the orbit:

- an ellipse if $2PN-\rho>0$;
- a hyperbola if $2PN-\rho<0$;
- a parabola if $2PN-\rho=0$.

For an ellipse or hyperbola we can now construct $N'$ and project it on the reflection of line PS about the normal, to find the second focus S'. For a parabola constructing the directrix is easy and is left to the reader.

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for this illustration and explanation. I've got a question though. Do we need to be given the acceleration $\vec{a}$ already in this development ? My understanding is that $\vec{a}$ can be derived from $\vec{r}$ and $\theta$, the true anomaly and has two components; one directed towards the S and one perpendicular to PS at P. Am I missing something ? Thanks once again.

Comment: The acceleration is given by $a=F/m$ and its direction is the same as the force. The law of gravitation implies a force directed towards $S$ (which is the position of the Sun, assumed at a fixed position). I don't understand your comment above.

Comment: I was thinking in the lines of polar coordinates  r⃗  and θ and when you derive $\vec{v}$ and $\vec{a}$, there is a component that is present in the perpendicular direction to PS at P. But when you think it in terms of the physics, since there is no perpendicular force in that direction, this component vanishes I think, I was referring to this component.

Comment: @mysterium By the way, the acceleration is given by $a=k/PS^2$, where $k$ is a constant. Hence it is known, once you know the position of $P$.

Comment: I published a GeoGebra construction of the orbit, using the above method: https://www.geogebra.org/m/qx264hqz

Comment: Thanks a lot, I've also tried to visualise this using geogebra, only for the case of an ellipse though. https://i.imgur.com/PLUPe7m.png. But your implementation incorporates all the eccentricity values and hence can be generalised to any conic section, Thanks a lot again.