# Is it possible to draw an ellipse given only the perimeter point tangent, and the distance & angles between that and one of the foci?

Tags: linear-algebra, trigonometry, conic-sections, coordinate-systems, tangent-line

*Full disclosure, I am a complete novice when it comes to this so if my terminology is off or I don't know some relatively basic things, that will be why.*

I am currently trying to determine the rest of the ellipse equation from the tangent angle of any point on the perimeter, with the distance and angle of that from one of the focuses.

For clarification I am creating a game with physically simulated orbits and I am trying to visualise them as lines with an ellipse. So essentially I would like to be able to draw that curve.

So the tangent angle on the perimeter is the absolute direction in space that the spacecraft would be travelling at that given moment, and the distance & angle form one of the foci would be the centre of the planet it is orbiting.

**This is the raw data I have available:**

Both Focus1 & perimeter point x,y co-ordinates

Angle to and from both points

Distance between both points

Tangent & normal angle of the point on the perimeter

**Here is a rough visualisation for what I'm getting at:**

[image]

***To clarify F2 or the centre are points I would like to calculate exactly, which already exist due to the simulation but I don't know***

The thing I was wondering was if there was some kind of constant between the distance and tangent angle that I could use. The equation that it would doesn't have to work universally at all angles either as I can code some logic to correct the final values.

Just that it would be ideal if I could simplify the mathematics as much as possible, not only for my limited experience but for game performance reasons too.

However if I'm completely missing some much simpler method then I would love to hear that too, especially if I've overlooked anything from the base ellipse equation. Also feel free to ask for anything I might have accidentally left out.

I appreciate your time :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short: the line perpendicular to the tangent at point $P$ (a.k.a.the normal) is the bisector of $\angle F_1PF_2$. Hence $F_2$ can be any point on ray $PF_1'$, the reflection of ray $PF_1$ about the normal. Any choice of $F_2$ will give a possible ellipse.

EDIT.

If the major axis of the ellipse lies on the horizontal line through $F_1$, then there is a unique answer (provided the normal doesn't pass through $F_1$): just take as $F_2$ the intersection between ray $PF_1'$ and that line.

Comment: Thanks that is indeed true, I know I didn't explain it too well in original post but F2 is the exact position I need to calculate, that or the centre would be very helpful.

The game I'm making calculates the physics already and the result is that the ship can orbit the planet, so it already creates its own ellipse. 
So the specific ellipse already exists but I can't access that because it is a real time simulation, so I need to calculate it from those values I have that I can access. With focal length available I will be able to calc a, then b using another method.

Any Ideas? Thanks

Comment: As I wrote above, infinite different solutions are possible, unless you add some other information. If you know the attraction force, for instance, then a unique ellipse can be singled out.

Comment: Ah indeed... lol, feel a bit foolish for overlooking that. I began to realise that somewhat just after posting my reply but how you said it sums it up perfectly. Seems like I completely forgot about it in my mad dash to dive into ellipse math. I do indeed have the figure for the attraction force as well, so in what way could I integrate it if you'd be so kind? thanks

Comment: If you have the attraction force, you can follow the construction outlined here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3868616/fixing-an-orbit-in-space-using-r-and-v-keplerian-orbits/3868810#3868810

Comment: I forgot: you also need to know the velocity at point $P$.

Comment: From your figure it looks like the ellipse you are looking for has its major axis along $x$ axis: if so, the ellipse is indeed unique. See my edit.